# Can I detect a char position using Regex with a prefix condition?

Tags: c#, regex, avalonedit

I have a string representing an equation statement: `a = b * c` in a tool I am writing.

The string may contains a "comment" suffix to the statement with `*` representing the comment.

I am using AvalonEdit for the text editor object and trying to write the proper XSHD file definition to match detect the comment string for highlighting.

I am not sure this can be detected by a regular expression as `*` char has two meaning based on the context of its usage.

E.g.,

1. `a = b * c` : `*` is the match multiply char, and is not signaling a comment (no comment highlighting)
2. `abcdef abcd  * a comment` : Here `*` is a comment char and the string `a comment` should be highlighted as comment
3. `a = b * c * a comment` : Here the first `*` is the match operator but the second is a comment char... so the string `a comment` should be highlighted as a comment

I tried the following definitions for Comment detection in the XSHD file:

`<Span color="Comment" begin="\*" end="\n" />`
This cleary solve the 2nd example... but it will wrongly set `c` as comment under example 1.

Then I tried `<Span color="Comment" begin="^(?!.*=.*\*).*?\*.*" end="\n" />` , use negative lookahead approach to solve example 1 but then it captures the whole string as comment on example 2.

Both definitions can't detect example 3 scenario.

I am wondering if my problem can't be solved by a regex (as XSHD requires) as `*` is used in two different meanings..

I am using AvalonEdit 5.0.4.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What constitutes a valid equation statement? Is _"a = b * c * a"_ a valid equation meaning _"a equals b multiplied by c multiplied by a"_ or is "a" a comment in that situation.

Comment: @PaulF: in this case the statement is `a = b*c    * a comment` - therefore the last `*` is the comment char, and the first is the math operator. two multiply operator in a single line is not supported so `a=b*c*a` (b multiply by c multiple by a) is not supported anyhow

Comment: I think this may be too complex for Regex - it requires parsing the first part of the line to check for it being a valid statement involving multiply. If * is allowed in the comment itself, that would complicate matters further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it really depends on how flexible your syntax is. However, with what you have provided, try this one:

```
\*\s?\w( ?[\w]+)+
```

Feel free to test it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/JYOs92/2).
With this one, you don't **need** to separate anything with spaces, but it will allow spaces. I have provided two test-lines in the regex101 down below, see if this will suit your needs.